# Changing slides using anchor tags or buttons from different div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, slide

I have a bootstrap carousel in my page and I want to change slides using anchor tags or buttons from different `div` how to do it?

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through jQuery.

```js
$('#nextButton').on('click', function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel('next');
});

$('#previousButton').on('click', function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one, you can use the href id in any div to handle the previous and next button
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rubhan/ok2ms939/1/

Comment: I want to navigate those slides in carousel from buttons in menu bar.

Comment: href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"  put this things in a nav bar botton